# Takes a list of strings and returns each line prepended by the correct number: Ruby

Tags: ruby

Working on a task to create a function which takes a list of strings and returns each line prepended by the correct number.

```
## Prepend each number to a list of strings sequentially. 

def number lines
  lines.map {|numbered_lines| numbered_lines.prepend("1: ")}
   
  end 

## Problem: How to create a list of numbers that prepend to list of strings???
```

for example

```
number ["a", "b", "c"] # => ["1: a", "2: b", "3: c"]
```

My code currently outputs the following:

```
 should add line numbers (1-based index)
Expected: ["1: a", "2: b", "3: c"], instead got: ["1: a", "1: b", "1: c"]
```

Any useful resources on how I can work around this type of task in future will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index) to start from index 1 instead of 0.

> Iterates the given block for each element with an index, which starts from offset

Try the below:

```
def number_lines
  ["a", "b", "c"].map.with_index(1){ |element, index| "#{index}: #{element}" }
end
```

#### About with_index

By default `with_index` iterates the block for every element starting from 0th index

```
["a", "b", "c"].each.with_index { |element, index| puts "index: #{index} element: #{element}" }
```

The above snippet will output the below:

```
index: 0 element: a
index: 1 element: b
index: 2 element: c
```

`with_index` also accepts an optional argument to identify which index to start from, You can use `with_index(3)` to use the starting index as 3. Please find the below example for better understanding:

```
["a", "b", "c"].each.with_index(3) { |element, index| puts "index: #{index} element: #{element}" }

# Output
index: 3 element: a
index: 4 element: b
index: 5 element: c
```

Comment: sorry could someone please explain how the block of code works after we have used the .with_index(1) method.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check whether it helps

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to other answers, you could do

```
def number(lines)
  (0...lines.size).each{|i| lines[i].prepend("#{i+1}: ")}
end
```

Note that this solution alters the input array itself and returns an enumerable range. If you don't want to modify the existing array, then I'd suggest:

```
def number(lines)
  (0...lines.size).map{|i| "#{i+1}: #{lines[i]}" }
end
```

I often prefer iterating over the index range itself rather than the list if I need the index. It's a bit shorter and only has a single extra variable, but it's really just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

will it work for you?

```
def number lines
  lines.each_with_index.map { |line,index| line.prepend("#{index} : ") }
end
```

Comment: `lines.map.with_index`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the improvement, can I update my answer as per your improvement ?

Comment: if I was to index from 1 and not 0 how would I do that? and if you could please explain how this code works that would be a huge plus. thanks!"

Comment: just add (index + 1) "lines.each_with_index.map { |line,index| line.prepend("#{index+1} : ") }"

Comment: okay I'm not sure why it's not passing ``` should add line numbers (1-based index)
Expected: ["1: a", "2: b", "3: c"], instead got: ["1 : a", "2 : b", "3 : c"]
 should handle empty strings
Expected: ["1: ", "2: ", "3: ", "4: ", "5: "], instead got: ["1 : ", "2 : ", "3 : ", "4 : ", "5 : "]```